# lua trig(pin,"down",pin1cb) questions

Tags: lua

Being new to lua, I didn't quite understand the trig example in the documentation.  https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/gpio/#gpiotrig

1) In "trig(pin, "down", pin1cb)", the pin1cb has no arguments, while in function pin1cb has the argument "level".  Why?  and what is "level"?

2) in "trig(pin, level == gpio.HIGH  and "down" or "up")", what's the value of level and where it is set?

Answer (score 0):

`gpio.trig(pin, [type [, callback_function]])` and `callback_function(level)` is supposed to mean that `callback_function` should be a function that will be called with one value as its argument (and in the description and the example, the argument is named 'level').

So

```
gpio.trig( 5, "both", function( v ) --[[callback code here]]  end )
```

should be a valid call (I'm naming the argument 'v' instead of 'level' - you can pick any name).

With that, (1) should be clearer:  `function pin1cb( level ) … end` defines a function that takes one argument, while in `trig(pin, "down", pin1cb)` this function is passed to `trig`.  (Functions exist independent of names, you can pass them around, assign them to local or global variables, … so here, the actual function – not the result of calling it or something like that – is passed as an argument.)

And (2): `level` is whatever gets passed as the argument to `pin1cb` when it's called.  According to the docs, "The level of the specified pin at the interrupt passed as the parameter to the callback."